# How to return filtered information in a foreach loop

Tags: php, google-ads-api

I want to filter information inside the foreach and to return as result only some of them.

This is the code :

```
    $keywords = "";
    $avgmonthly = "";
    $compet ="";
    foreach ($response->getResults() as $result) {
        $avgmonthly = $result->getKeywordIdeaMetrics()->getAvgMonthlySearches()->getValue();
        $compet = $result->getKeywordIdeaMetrics()->getCompetition();
        $log = $this->getLogger();
        $log->err($response->serializeToJsonString());

        if ($avgmonthlysearch > 10 && $competition== 4) {
            $keywords .= $result->getText()->getValue() . ",";
        }
    }
        return $keywords;
```

in my log i see this results:

```
{"results":[{"text":"world","keywordIdeaMetrics": 
{"avgMonthlySearches":"140","competition":"HIGH"}}, 
{"text":"today ","keywordIdeaMetrics":{"avgMonthlySearches":"10","competition":"HIGH"{"text":"office","keywordIdeaMetrics":{"avgMonthlySearches":"5","competition":"LOW"}}
```

when i try to call this function i get this error : `Fatal error: Uncaught Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError: Call to a member function getAvgMonthlySearches() on null`

Comment: The error tell you that $result->getKeywordIdeaMetrics() is null and your function cannot be call from that.

You have to check $result->getKeywordIdeaMetrics() before call your method

Comment: @MelvynMarigny please can you give me an idea how to check ? Thank you

Comment: @MelvynMarigny  i debug my code and what i found is that normal result should be like : "text":"today","keywordIdeaMetrics":{"avgMonthlySearches":"10","competition":"LOW"}} but the case where i got the error is when is only text : {"text":"tomorrow "} or {"avgMonthlySearches":"10","competition":"HIGH"} i don't know how to escape this cases

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your goal is just to espace this case, you can add an if condition ( As $result->getKeywordIdeaMetrics() can be null, it will not go inside this if condition )

```
foreach ($response->getResults() as $result) {
    if ($result->getKeywordIdeaMetrics()) {
        $avgmonthly = $result->getKeywordIdeaMetrics()->getAvgMonthlySearches()->getValue();
        $compet = $result->getKeywordIdeaMetrics()->getCompetition();
    }

    $log = $this->getLogger();
    $log->err($response->serializeToJsonString());

    if ($avgmonthlysearch > 10 && $competition== 4) {
       $keywords .= $result->getText()->getValue() . ",";
    }
}
```